# Enviar parametro por medio POST a traves de ajax y recibirlo en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Se que este titulo "Enviar parámetro  por medio POST a través de ajax y recibirlo en PHP" es un tema común en este foro...y créanme, he buscado en varios post intentando dar con la solución a mi problema, pero no lo he conseguido, por eso he recurrido a ustedes, a ver si me echan una mano.

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña app que me muestra en una pantalla una serie de resultados de formulas SQL (count, select, etc...) que hago sobre mi Base de datos.
Esos registros se agrupan por fecha en mi base de datos, por lo que deseo tener en esa pantalla un datePicker para ir seleccionando a través de una consulta SQL que día quiero que me muestre.
Hasta ahí estoy bien, ya que las consultas sql funcionan y retornan los datos requeridos, pero cuando quiero enviar la petición de la fecha a traves del datePicker, la pantalla no realiza cambio alguno. Les dejo el codigo para que me entiendan mejor. 
En sí, tengo dos problemas principalmente.

1. Los indices que ejecuto en el archivo **escritorio.php** ($data_1,$data_2, etc...) me tiran un error de 'undefined index'. Probé colocando el codigo en donde se generan estos indices directamente en el archivo **escritorio.php** y me soluciona el problema de los indices indefinidos, pero despues no tengo como pasarle el valor del **datePicker** que envié desde el ajax.
2. La consulta que solicita el valor del `datePicker` por medio de Ajax y se rescata por medio de la variable **POST** no me esta devolviendo el valor que el usuario selecciona del fechero o datePicker. Lo asume como valor vació, seguramente porque estoy haciendo mal la petición Ajax, pero no logro ver donde.... :'(.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Así debiera verse (asi se ve solo cuando le doy un valor estático de la fecha directamente en la consulta a la base de datos) 
[image: Asi debiera verse]

Así se ve
[image: Asi se ve]

escritorio.php

```
<?php
//Activamos el almacenamiento en el buffer

ob_start();

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["nombre"]))
   {
header("Location: login.html");
   }
else
   { 
require 'header.php'; 

if ($_SESSION['escritorio']==1){


     <!--Contenido-->
     <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
     <div class="content-wrapper">        
     <!-- Main content -->
     <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border" >
                      <h1 class="box-title">Escritorio > Motivos del <?php echo date("d");?> de <?php echo date("m");?> del <?php echo date("Y");?> </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i></span>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="date" class="form-control" name="datePicker" id="datePicker" required></span>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnactualizar" onclick="actualizar_escritorio($('#datePicker').val());return false;"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <!-- centro -->
                <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                  <!-- Tabs -->
                  <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">Período 1 (08:00 - 10:00)</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">Período 2 (10:00 - 12:00)</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">Período 3 (12:00 - 14:00)</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#tab_4" data-toggle="tab">Período 4 (14:00 - 17:00)</a></li>

                      <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
                        <b>Período 1</b>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php  for($i=0;$i<count($data_1);$i++){ ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                              <div class="text-center color-palette-set">
                                  <div class="bg-blue disabled color-palette" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
                                    <h2>
                                      <strong><?php echo $data_1[$i][0]; ?></strong>
                                    </h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="bg-blue color-palette">
                                    <p><?php echo $data_1[$i][1];?></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
                      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_2">
                        <b>Período 2</b>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php  for($i=0;$i<count($data_2);$i++){ ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                              <div class="text-center color-palette-set">
                                  <div class="bg-green disabled color-palette" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
                                    <h2>
                                      <strong><?php echo $data_2[$i][0]; ?></strong>
                                    </h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="bg-green color-palette">
                                    <p><?php echo $data_2[$i][1];?></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
                      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_3">
                        <b>Período 3</b>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php  for($i=0;$i<count($data_3);$i++){ ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                              <div class="text-center color-palette-set">
                                  <div class="bg-yellow disabled color-palette" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
                                    <h2>
                                      <strong><?php echo $data_3[$i][0]; ?></strong>
                                    </h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="bg-yellow color-palette">
                                    <p><?php echo $data_3[$i][1];?></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_4">
                        <b>Período 4</b>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php  for($i=0;$i<count($data_4);$i++){ ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                              <div class="text-center color-palette-set">
                                  <div class="bg-purple disabled color-palette" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
                                    <h2>
                                      <strong><?php echo $data_4[$i][0]; ?></strong>
                                    </h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="bg-purple color-palette">
                                    <p><?php echo $data_4[$i][1];?></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.tab-content -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- nav-tabs-custom -->
                </div>
                <!--Fin centro -->
              </div><!-- /.box -->
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </section><!-- /.content -->

  </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <!--Fin-Contenido-->
  <?php
   }
   else
     {
   require 'noacceso.php';
      }

  require 'footer.php';
     ?>
   <!--<script src="scripts/consultas.js"></script>-->
   <script src="../public/jquery-knob/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
   <script src="../public/js/chart.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../public/js/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

   <?php 
    }
    ob_end_flush();
    ?>
```

consulta.php

```
<?php
  require_once "../modelos/Consultas.php";

  $consulta=new Consultas();

  $datePicker = isset($_POST['fechaSelect'])? strtotime(limpiarCadena($_POST['fechaSelect'])):time(); // Hora actual

  $datePicker=date('Y-m-d',$datePicker);
  echo $datePicker;


  switch ($_GET["op"]){
          case 'actualizar_escritorio':

                $rspta_1=$consulta->periodo_1($datePicker);
                $rspta_2=$consulta->periodo_2($datePicker);
                $rspta_3=$consulta->periodo_3($datePicker);
                $rspta_4=$consulta->periodo_4($datePicker);

                $data_1=Array();
                $data_2=Array();
                $data_3=Array();
                $data_4=Array();

                while ($reg=$rspta_1->fetch_object()) {
                    $data_1[]=array(
                        "0"=>$reg->cantidad,
                        "1"=>$reg->nom_motivo
                    );  
                }

                while ($reg=$rspta_2->fetch_object()) {
                    $data_2[]=array(
                        "0"=>$reg->cantidad,
                        "1"=>$reg->nom_motivo
                    );
                }

                while ($reg=$rspta_3->fetch_object()) {
                    $data_3[]=array(
                        "0"=>$reg->cantidad,
                        "1"=>$reg->nom_motivo
                    );
                }

                while ($reg=$rspta_4->fetch_object()) {
                    $data_4[]=array(
                        "0"=>$reg->cantidad,
                        "1"=>$reg->nom_motivo
                    );
                }

               echo json_encode($data_1 && $data_2 && $data_3 && $data_4);
               break;
      }
 ?>
```

consulta.js

```
     //Función que se ejecuta al inicio
       function init(){

           setInputDate("#datePicker");//Coloca la fecha actual en el contenedor #datePicker del HTML
           setInputDate("#fecha");
           actualizar_escritorio(fechaSelect);
     }

          //selecciona la fecha actual del cliente en base a su zona horaria
           function setInputDate(_id){
                    var _dat = document.querySelector(_id);
                    var hoy = new Date(),
                          d = hoy.getDate(),
                          m = hoy.getMonth()+1, 
                          y = hoy.getFullYear(),
                              data;

                         if(d < 10){
                          d = "0"+d;
                                   };
                         if(m < 10){
                          m = "0"+m;
                                   };

                         data = y+"-"+m+"-"+d;
                         console.log(data);
                        _dat.value = data;

                       //Función cancelar formulario
           function cancelarform(){
                    limpiar();
                    mostrarform(false);
                    }

           function actualizar_escritorio(fechaSelect){

                    var parametros = {"fechaSelect" : fechaSelect};

           $.ajax({
                  data: parametros,
                  url: '../ajax/consultas.php?op=actualizar_escritorio',
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType : "json",                        
                      error: function(e){
                             console.log(e.responseText);   
                  }
     });
  }

     init();
```

Comment: En el **$_POST['fechaSelect']** en dónde está el elemento **fechaSelect** con ese **id** en el html?

Comment: Cuando haces esta llamada: `actualizar_escritorio(fechaSelect);` la variable `fechaSelect` no existe. ¿Dónde recoges la fecha realmente?

Comment: Cuando llamo a la función `actualizar_escritorio()` del archivo **consulta.js** almacenado en el <button> del html, le envio en valor que posee el contenedor #datePicker.... Esa función recibe el valor con el nombre `fechaSelect` y la envía la petición ajax por medio de la variable parámetros.

Comment: O eso es como creo que debería funcionar..... Ahora que me lo mencionan, probare colocar el mismo nombre durante todo el proceso, tanto en el html como en el php.... y veré si resulta.....